# Why does this code not work? Javascript and HTML. Please see the details

Tags: javascript, html

This is my HTML file.

```
   <body>
            <header>
                <h3 id = "TestID"> Test </h3>
            </header>
        </body>

        <script src = "MessagingPage.js"></script>
```

This is my JS file

```
document.getElementById("TestID").addEventListener("load", function(){
this.innerHTML("Hi");
})

document.write("Hello World");
```

Now, when I load the HTML, I get "Test" in the browser. However, what needs to be there is "Hi". I do not understand why this happens. Can you please help me understand? I am just getting started, so please explain in simple terms.

Thanks for taking the time to read through this :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two problems.

---

Only elements which load external content have a `load` event (such as an `iframe` or `img`).

The `h3` isn't loading any external content so has no `load` event.

Perhaps you should bind your event handler to the `window`.

---

`innerHTML` is a *string*, not a function.

---

```js
addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("TestID").innerHTML = "Hi";
})

document.write("Hello World");
```

```html
  <header>
    <h3 id="TestID"> Test </h3>
  </header>

<script src="MessagingPage.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is true. But it's worth noting a couple of things. You can call  `addEventListener` wihtou adding a variable at the beginning because every global object in a browser is interpreted as if it was used on the `window` object. So `addEventListener` is the same as `window.addEventListener`. And placing a `script` tag outside of the `body` is not valid html. It will work in most browser though, but the html spec forbids it

Answer (score 0):

Including the script inside `<body>` and updating the JS file will resolve the problem.

**Here is the example of working code:**

**Updated HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Demo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h3 id = "TestID"> Test </h3>
    </header>
    <script src = "/MessagingPage.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Updated JS:**

```
// MessagingPage.js
document.getElementById("TestID").innerHTML = "Hi"
document.write("Hello World");
```

**Output:**

[image]